# Hapi inject won't exit to command line after the test is done using gulp

Tags: javascript, node.js, gulp, hapi.js

I'm trying to do a simple integration testing but after the test is done it won't exit to command line. It's just stuck there.

Here's the code.

```
'use strict';

var Hapi = require('hapi');
var Inert = require('inert');
var Vision = require('vision');

var log = require('./logger');
var config = require('./config');
var extensions = require('./extensions');

var server = new Hapi.Server({});
server.connection({ port: config.port });
require('./routes')(server);

// adds metadata to responses, and customizes error responses
server.ext({
  type: 'onPreResponse',
  method: function preResponse(request, reply) {
    extensions.handlePreResponse(request, reply);
    return reply.continue();
  }
});

server.on('request-error', extensions.handleOnRequestError);

server.register(
  [
    Inert,
    Vision,
    require('./plugins/swaggerPlugin')
  ],
  function handlePluginRegistrationError(err) {
    if (err) {
      log.warn(JSON.stringify(err));
      throw err; // something bad happened loading the plugins
    }
    server.start(function serverStartedCallback() {
      log.warn('DAL services listening on port '+config.port+'...');
      log.warn('Server running at: ' + server.info.uri);
    });
  }
);

module.exports = server;
```

Here's the test

```
'use strict';

var chai = require('chai');
var expect = chai.expect;
var server = require('../../../index');

describe('Root Integration Tests', function desc() {
  it('should get root route', function it(done) {
    var options = {
      method: "GET",
      url: "/"
    };
    server.inject(options, function(response) {
      expect(response.statusCode).to.equal(200);
      done();
    });
  });
});
```

Here's my gulp.

```
gulp.task('integration-test', function performIntegrationTests() {
  return gulp.src(['tests/integration/**/*.js'])
    .pipe(mocha({'reporter': 'dot', 'timeout': 30000}));
});
```

Comment: I would use lab with npm to run your test's, see an example of testing [here](https://github.com/hapijs/university/blob/master/test/index.js).  Once you make switch you won't have any problems with testing.  The issue probably related to the module.export at bottom of file.  Export a function that wraps hapi in a closure and require for your tests.

Comment: You know one of the benefits of `server.inject()` is that you don't need to start the server?

Answer (score 1):

What is likely the issue is that hapi still has it's http server running, so node doesn't know to exit.

Try adding an `after` block to your test and calling `server.stop()` there. Something like this:

```
after(function(done) {
  server.stop({ timeout: 0 }, done)
})
```